# Randomization of pairs and ordering in R

Tags: r, random, statistics

I'm afraid I can't find the answer to this so I need your expertise.

I need to randomize a set of data in R, where the datasets are sets of choices (represented by letters here) in pairs; however, I also need to, for each set, randomize the order of precedence (which goes first). Additionally, I need to include a negative control (XX). It would look something like this:

```
(1) X A or A X

(2) X B or B X

(3) X C or C X

(4) X D or D X

(5) X E or E X

(6) XX
```

I can randomize 1-6 easy enough using `sample(1:6, 4)`, but I don't know how to add in randomization for the pair order as well. Any ideas are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your original set of data looks like this:

```
li
[[1]]
[1] "X" "A"

[[2]]
[1] "X" "B"

[[3]]
[1] "X" "C"

[[4]]
[1] "X" "D"

[[5]]
[1] "X" "E"

[[6]]
[1] "X" "X"
```

You can randomize it both at the level of list and at the level of each pair as this:

```
lapply(li, function(pair) pair[sample(1:2)])[sample(1:6)]
[[1]]
[1] "X" "D"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "X"

[[3]]
[1] "E" "X"

[[4]]
[1] "X" "X"

[[5]]
[1] "X" "A"

[[6]]
[1] "C" "X"
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question, the below is a little brute force, but I believe answers your question

```
s<- c("a","b","c","d","e","x")
n<-6

(x<-cbind(sample(s,n),rep("x",n)))

for (i in 1:n) {
  if(sample(1:2,1)==2) {
    tmp<-x[i,1]
    x[i,1] <- x[i,2]
    x[i,2] <- tmp
  }   
}
x
```

Comment: Psidom's solution is easily more efficient than the one i just posted.

Comment: That's ok, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand; you have `LETTERS[1:5]` and `LETTERS[24]` (`X`) that you are sampling from twice, with random ordering. This should do it;

```
c(sample(LETTERS[c(1:5, 24)], 1), LETTERS[24])[sample(2)]
```

Broken down;

```
c(                               ## combination of
sample(LETTERS[c(1:5, 24)], 1),  ## A:E, X, sampled once
LETTERS[24])                     ## and X
[sample(2)]                      ## re-sampled
```

e.g.

```
set.seed(1337)
[1] "X" "D"
```

A list of some possible outcomes;

```
set.seed(1337)
replicate(10, c(sample(LETTERS[c(1:5, 24)], 1), LETTERS[24])[sample(2)])
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "X"  "C"  "X"  "X"  "E"  "X"  "C"  "E"  "X"  "X"  
[2,] "D"  "X"  "X"  "A"  "X"  "A"  "X"  "X"  "D"  "X"
```

Comment: Jonathan, Your output doesn't shown any "X"/"B" combinations. Is there a variant that forces all 6 combinations before repeating?

Comment: That wouldn't be random. Set the replications higher (e.g. 100 with the same seed) and you get "X"/"B" in repetitions 12, 14, 50, 52, 64, 80, 84, 85, and 89.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was 'reading into' the question figuring that Elise was randomizing a questionnaire and the responses, or something along that line. (In any case I learned something by your answer ... neat.)